# Need to show year in menubar

Tags: indicator

I need to take a screen shot in ubuntu 12.10 with the whole time stamp including the year in it.
Is there any way to do this ?
Clicking the time opens the calendar, with year, but I cannot take the screen shot while the calendar is dropped down.
Please help me.

Comment: You can set a delay of 2-3 seconds for the screenshot. That gives you time to open the calendar and have it be shown when the screenshot is taken. This works for most any dropdown menu.

Comment: ooppzz...
that's awesome....
I haven't noted that........
thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dconf-editor`: (if you don't have it in your system, install it with: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`)

Navigate to: `com > canonical > indicator > datetime`

1. Change `time-format` to `custom`
2. Enter to the `custom-time-format` the preferred layout (ex. `%d-%m-%Y %l:%M %p`) according to the [strftime's syntax.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/strftime.3.html)

Close `dconf-editor`, and you are done!

" The format of the time and/or date that is visible on the panel when using
              the indicator.  For most users this will be a set of predefined values as
              determined by the configuration utility, but advanced users can change it
              to anything strftime can accept.  Look at the man page on strftime for
              more information."

Comment: Thx for the edit, Florian Diesch!

Comment: +1 Great answer but I show `com > canonical > **indicator** > datetime` in dconf in 12.04. Has it changed in 12.10 or is that a typo?

Comment: Tom: sorry, it was my mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type the command

```
xclock -digital
```

The default display is "Day dd Mth Year Hh:Mm:Ss Zon"

Comment: Yep, or type `date` in Terminal. ;) fabricator, the question was about the indicator's time format.

Comment: Question was about taking a screen shot with the date as well as the time visible...